# Proof that the support function of the Euclidean unit ball is $|x|$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The support function of a set $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as the following

$$
S_A=\sup_{y \in A} x^Ty
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $A=B_1=\|x\|_2<1$.

Show that the support function of the Euclidean unit ball is $|x|$.

I tried the following by defining the Lagrangian function

$$
L(y,\lambda)=x^Ty+\lambda(\|y\|_2^2-1)
$$
Because $\|y\|_2^2 <1$ and $\|y\|_2 <1$ are the same.

I do not know how to proceed?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Writing Lagrange function for the constraint and using first order optimal condition.

Comment: try to include your attempt in your post?

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh: I included my try, could you complete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=0$, the solution is obvious. Suppose $x \ne 0$,

$$
L(y,\lambda)=x^Ty+\lambda(\|y\|_2^2-1)
$$

We want to solve for $y$, hence differentiating with respect to $y$,

$$x+2\lambda y = 0$$

If $\lambda =0$, then $x=0$. Hence, $\lambda \ne 0$.

$$y = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}x$$

That is we know that $y$ must be parallel to $x$, let's write $y = \frac{kx}{\|x\|}$, $|k|\le 1$.

The problem is now $$\sup_{|k| \le 1} kx^T\frac{x}{\|x\|}=\sup_{|k|\le 1}k\|x\|=\|x\|.$$

Remark:

Cauchy-Schwarz seems to be the natural approach to me.

Comment: What is the rational for choosing $|k| \leq 1$, we can choose any $k$ to make them to be in parallel, then the answer of $\sup$ becomes $k_{max}\|x\|$?

Comment: $y$ is inside the unit ball, the length can't exceed $1$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I should be more careful.  Could you help me and answer my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989610/why-support-function-describes-the-signed-distances-of-supporting-hyperplanes?

Comment: hmmm... no idea what is the wiki talking about... i might have missed something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=B_1$. We can assume that $x \ne 0$.

For $y \in A$ we have , by Cauchy-Schwarz: $x^Ty \le ||x||_2 ||y||_2 \le ||x||_2$, hence

$(1) \quad S_A \le ||x||_2$.

Now let $t>1$ and put $y_t:= \frac{1}{t||x||_2}x$, then $y_t \in A$ and $x^Ty_t=\frac{1}{t}||x||_2 \le S_A$ With $t \to1$ we get

$(2) \quad ||x||_2 \le S_A$.

The result follows now from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Can you help me to show it in a way that I tried?